# Improve mysql query speed with long date range condition

Tags: mysql

I have a two table:table_car and table_order:
[image]
[image]

I want a table like this:
[image]

table_order has composite key (id_type,date)

```
SELECT "September" AS `Range`,
SUM(IF(id_type IN(1,2), items,0)) AS 'RedandBlue_items',
SUM(IF(id_type IN(3,4), items,0)) AS 'YellowandGreen_items',
SUM(IF(id_type IN(1,2), items,0)) AS 'RedandBlue_amount',
SUM(IF(id_type IN(3,4), items,0)) AS 'YellowandGreen_amount' 
FROM table_order 
WHERE id_type IN(1,2,3,4) AND `date` >= "2015-09-01" AND `date` <= "2015-09-30"
UNION
SELECT 
"August" AS `Range`,
SUM(IF(id_type IN(1,2), items,0)) AS 'RedandBlue_items',
SUM(IF(id_type IN(3,4), items,0)) AS 'YellowandGreen_items',
SUM(IF(id_type IN(1,2), items,0)) AS 'RedandBlue_amount',
SUM(IF(id_type IN(3,4), items,0)) AS 'YellowandGreen_amount' 
FROM table_order 
WHERE id_type IN(1,2,3,4) AND `date` >= "2015-08-01" AND `date` <= "2015-08-31"
```

Are there any others way to query faster? Let say I have a table with billion records and can execute long date range query in the condition, like date >= "2015-01-01" and date <= "2016-01-01" for example. 
You can find sample here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1787e/1

Comment: sure, de-normalize it.

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Comment: what is the datatype of `date`

Comment: @Drew: the datatype of date is datetime

Comment: @Drew: yes it need to be datetime. But if you have any better suggestion?

Comment: you need the time in there ?

Comment: @Drew: I saved time in another two columns, such as: time_begin and time_end. For example: from 09:00:00 to 10:00:00. But in this example just need date

Comment: be that as it may, this column is a datetime. Your composite is 12 bytes wide, plus the query does an `in()`. You *could* get the composite keylen down to 3 bytes. And where start and end are the same date, you are taxing it by an extra comparison. A prepared stmt would handle that

Comment: but I am not writing that up, not on this website. Off to sleep

Comment: @Drew: sorry I got a mistake, the datatype for date column is date, just like you see in the picture. I'm not use datetime actually. Do you know another way to select, maybe different as UNION ?

Comment: @sontd Your query does not seem right - you have no GROUP BY and the sums will sum the same values, the IF should be inside the sum() probably. You can select `date` from the table directly, no need to add it as a constant in the UNIONed queries. Make the query right and only then think about speed.

Comment: @jkavalik: I can use group by but I need a group Red&Blue, Yellow&Green data, if I use group by it will separate to 2 different rows. see in my question, I edited query a bit to get data of two months

Comment: @sontd the sums look better now, but you can probably get rid of the union by grouping on the date. Can you try to prepare an example on  http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: @ jkavalik: I made an example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1787e/1. Could you take a look? I see this query not use indexs so it will take long time

Answer (score 1):

Using the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT date_format(`date`, '%M') AS `Range`,
SUM(IF(id_type IN(1,2), items,0)) AS 'RedandBlue_items',
SUM(IF(id_type IN(3,4), items,0)) AS 'YellowandGreen_items',
SUM(IF(id_type IN(1,2), items,0)) AS 'RedandBlue_amount',
SUM(IF(id_type IN(3,4), items,0)) AS 'YellowandGreen_amount' 
FROM `order`
WHERE id_type IN(1,2,3,4) AND `date` >= "2015-08-01" AND `date` <= "2015-09-30"
group by year(`date`), month(`date`)
order by year(`date`) desc, month(`date`) desc;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d76254/2

Or keep your query with the union if you are always going for just two months. But if the range can be a lot bigger then I suggest using the modified one, it is much simpler to write and the grouping should not be the performance bottleneck if you select only a relatively small part of the table.

The `GROUP BY` variant can be made faster if you store the year-month in a separate column, so no functions are needed, and modify indexes accordingly. Your variant can use indexes well without modifications.

Your example (on the fiddle) does not show index usage because you have too few rows in the table and the query will have to read all of them anyway. But you can add a [covering index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) `(id_type, date, items)` (just extending the one you already have is enough, no need to keep the shorter one) which helps both versions of the query.

Just check explains:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d76254/1
- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d76254/2

Comment: great! it will useful with month or year data.
that's what I need, but one more problem: sometimes I want to use the condition like this: `date` >= "2015-08-15" AND `date` <= "2015-09-15". So with your query we cannot group by, isn't it?

Comment: @sontd if you want just one group from that range and not two then you are right, this simple group by won't make it. You might create an expression which would work or use your original solution.

Answer (score 0):

1) your example shows `sum(items)`for the amount, which I suppose is a copy error.

2) Possibly `GROUP_CONCAT` is what you're looking for

[MySQL Doku](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

[Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try with indexes. Very helpful in many cases: [Mysql Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Comment: I used indexes for this table: (id_type,date)

Comment: So you cannot get more from that. Fine :D I hope that you will get more optimization ideas ;)